# Can I return std::thread

Tags: c++, multithreading

Is it safe to return std::thread from a function?

eg

```
std::thread getWindowThread(std::function<void()> f){
    std::thread t(f);
    return t;
}

std::function<void()> func = [](){};
std::thread winT = getWindowThread(func);
winT.join();
```

Comment: Yes, the code has defined behavior and works as you expect it to. Is there any reason you have doubts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's safe, as long as the function's return value is used to initialize  or assign to another `std::thread` object.

The only precondition for `std::thread`'s destructor is that `joinable()` is `false`:

[[thread.thread.destr]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/thread.thread.destr)

> `~thread();`
>       *Effects:* If `joinable()`, calls `terminate()`. Otherwise, has no effects.

To be `joinable()`, the thread must have an ID not equal to a value-initialized ID:

[[thread.thread.member]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/thread.thread.member#2)

> `bool joinable() const noexcept;`
>       *Returns:* `get_­id()` != `id()`.

And `std::thread`'s move constructor and move-assignment operator specify that a moved-from thread will have an ID equal to a value-initalized ID, and therefore will not be `joinable()`:

[[thread.thread.constr]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/thread.thread.constr#11)

> `thread(thread&& x) noexcept;`
>       *Postconditions:* `x.get_­id() == id()` and `get_­id()` returns the value of `x.get_­id()` prior to the start of construction.

[[thread.thread.assign]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/thread.thread.assign)

> `thread& operator=(thread&& x) noexcept;`
>       ...
>       *Postconditions:* `x.get_­id() == id()` and `get_­id()` returns the value of `x.get_­id()` prior to the assignment.
>       ...

Since `getWindowThread` returns a function-local variable, its return value will be move-constructed from the returned object, and since `winT` will be move-constructed from the value returned by `getWindowThread`, your example is safe.  The returned `thread` object is no longer `joinable` and can be destroyed.

However, if the returned value is *not* used to initialize or assign to another `std::thread` object, its destructor will call `std::terminate()` and crash your program.  For this reason, I would recommend adding the `[[nodiscard]]` attribute to your function to ensure your compiler at least issues a warning in this dangerous situation (if you have access to C++17 features, otherwise there are compiler-specific extensions to enable the same behavior):

```
[[nodiscard]] std::thread getWindowThread(std::function<void()> f) {
    std::thread t(f);
    return t;
}
```

Comment: I have a follow up question regarding gmock for returning the thread eg: std::function<void()> lamda = [](){}; std::thread wThread(lamda); EXPECT_CALL(<obj>, getWindowThread(_)).WillRepeatedly(Return(wThread)); This throws exception as thread cant be copied. How can I return the mock ?

Comment: @vedikaseth Google's documentation covers that [here](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/cook_book.md#mocking-methods-that-use-move-only-types).  If you're still not sure what to do you should ask that as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's safe. That thread will be moved to winT.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look [std::thread's constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread). You can check that `std::thread` copy constructor (and copy assignment) has been deleted. See [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor) to learn more about `move constructor` in C++.

When you return std::thread from the function, it's returned object is move-constructed and your variable `winT` will also be move-constructed as the function returns an object having value category [prvalue](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category).

```
std::thread winT = getWindowThread(func);
```

This should work and won't cause any undefined behavior. You might be thinking that once you return `std::thread` from the function, it will be destroyed and it's resources must be released and may be it's thread might be destroyed.

But as stated earlier, the object created in function will be move-constructed to construct `winT` object.

**Detailed Information:**
[This](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/~thread) link says that:

> If *this has an associated thread (joinable() == true), std::terminate() is called.

So, to safely destroyed any std::thread object, you need to make sure it is not `joinable`. [joinable()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/joinable) gives more insight on this:

> So a default constructed thread is not joinable. A thread that has finished executing code, but has not yet been joined is still considered an active thread of execution and is therefore joinable.

So, when move constructor of `winT` constructs it, it [swaps](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap) itself with object returned from your function. After that, temporary of your function will be destroyed and since, it won't be joinable, it is safe to destroy it.